# How do I locate a element in my arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I'm a student and in my class we are programming a litte snake game, now the Problem ist that some times whene an Apple is eaten the game will freez, we figured out that it is propably caused by 2 Apples spawning at the same Position but we don't know how to avoid that. The Apples are generated in an arraylist so I think we need to locate the Elements inside the arraylist to say the Programm it is not allowed to spawn them there and needs to search for a new location until is has found one whithout an existing apple.

I searched on the Internet if there is a solution for my problem but i think it is a bit to specific or I follow the wrong path and some of you will find what I can't.

If you need any more details just write me a message. I'm glad to help you on helping me :D .

```
private void createApples(int max) {

    int loop = 0;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    Element apple;
    boolean exists;
    int index;


    for (loop = 0; loop < max; loop++) {
      exists = false;

      do {
        appleX = 
            new Random().nextInt(bounds.width / SNAKE_SIZE) * 
            SNAKE_SIZE + SNAKE_SIZE / 2;
        appleY =
            new Random().nextInt(bounds.height / SNAKE_SIZE) *
            SNAKE_SIZE + SNAKE_SIZE / 2;

        index = 0;
        while (index < apples.size() && !exists) {
          exists = apples.get(index).equal(appleX, appleY);
          index++;
        }



        if (!exists) 
          exists = player.contains(appleX, appleY);
          exists = player2.contains(appleX, appleY);



      }
      while (exists);

      apple = new Element(appleX, appleY, SNAKE_SIZE, Color.white, bounds);
      apples.add(apple);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't ` exists = player.contains(appleX, appleY);
          exists = player2.contains(appleX, appleY);` need to put in `{}` block?

Comment: Besides you write `while(exists);`, if `exists` is true, the program gets stucked with dead loop. I would throw exception instead of `while(exists);`

Answer (score 2):

Without going through your code in detail:

```
if (!exists) 
  exists = player.contains(appleX, appleY);
  exists = player2.contains(appleX, appleY);
```

without curly braces, you are just applying the condition to the first line here. This is what your computer will see:

```
if (!exists){
  exists = player.contains(appleX, appleY);
}

exists = player2.contains(appleX, appleY);
```

and this means, no matter what you have computed already for `exists` - it will be overwritten by whatever is true for `player2`.

But your exists should be true, whenever it is true for `player1` OR `player2`.

You can use the following instead:

```
  exists |= player.contains(appleX, appleY);
  exists |= player2.contains(appleX, appleY);
```

(Shorthand for)

```
if (!exists) 
   exists = player.contains(appleX, appleY);

if (!exists) 
   exists = player2.contains(appleX, appleY);
```

---

Can you add information, what `apples` is (type), and how your `equals / hashcode` method on `Element` is implemented?

```
while (index < apples.size() && !exists) {
  exists = apples.get(index).equal(appleX, appleY);
  index++;
}
```

(I guess you implented your own, cause you also called it `equal` instead of `equals`)

Comment: apples = new ArrayList<Element>();
    createApples(50);
  
public boolean equal(int x, int y) {
    return (this.x == x && this.y == y);
  }

Do you mean this?

Comment: @xenerax yes. That looks fine. So, your equal is just comparing x/y coordinates. so it's okay. Just take care, that you don't confuse it with `equals()` (note the trailing 's', cause the `equals` method by definition requires a parameter of type `Element` in that case.), so after applying the modification mentioned, you should have no more duplicate apples.